# JQPlot - Minimum width on horizontal stacked bar charts

Tags: jqplot

I have a small number of data points, with a large range of values.  I'm using the LogAxisRenderer to help display this, but there are still values that are so small that the bar's width is smaller than the label, and the bar may be almost invisible, just a few pixels wide.

What I'd like to be able to do is set a minimum width (say 20 pixels), so that the bar is never less than the minimum, and the label will fit within the bar.  I've seen this in another graph library (flash-based, unfortunately).  But I don't think there is a way to do it with jqplot.

My question is: is there a way to do this within jqplot?  If not, how would I go about making changes to the library to allow this?  I know javascript but I'm not familiar with the internals of jqplot, so if someone could point me in the right direction, it would be great!

See this example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9bcJ/11/

Here is the code:

```
plot4 = $.jqplot('bar_chart', data, {
    animate: true,
    stackSeries: true,
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesColors: ['#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#ff0000'],
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        shadowAngle: 135,
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal',
            highlightMouseDown: true
        },
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            formatString: '%d',
            hideZeros: true
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
            showTicks: false,
            drawMajorGridlines: false
        },
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    mark: null,
                    fontSize: 14
                }
            },
            ticks: ticks
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a link to the graph image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N5eD.jpg

Comment: To do this properly your larger values would then push the plot increasingly wide.  If you just forced your smaller values to be 20px regardless of value, than your plot would be misrepresenting the data.

Comment: True, the plot would not be exactly correct, but that's my requirement, and this capability is supported in other graph libraries. I'm just looking for an answer to my question, which is the best approach to modifying jqPlot to support this.